# adding content using append - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, append

I am trying to add content (div) after an image using append(). All the list items are dynamically generated, I can only add class to the 'ul'.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/ggyDf/3/

```
<ul class="footer-8-flickr">
  <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"></a></li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"></a></li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"></a></li>
<ul>

$("ul.footer-8-flickr li a img").append("<div class='overlay'><p>Content</p></div>");
```

May be I am missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `after` instead of `append` .

Take a look at

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggyDf/4/)**

```
<ul class="footer-8-flickr">
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"/></a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"/></a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"/></a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"/></a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"/></a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"/></a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"/></a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> <img src="#"/></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<img>` is valid HTML5 closing tag.

Comment: @RahilWazir: Thanks for correcting, even I was a bit confused initially

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert an element inside an `img` element, instead you can insert it after the `img` element as the next sibling

```
$("ul.footer-8-flickr li a img").after("<div class='overlay'><p>Content</p></div>");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rx78V/)

You can use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot Insert content in an `img` element.

Try this

```
$("ul.footer-8-flickr li a").append("<div class='overlay'><p>Content</p></div>");
```

It'll add `div` after `img` tag as a sibling.

Comment: I wanted it to insert it after img

Answer (score 2):

You can't append in `img` element because it is self closing tag instead append it to `a` element.

```
$("ul.footer-8-flickr li a").append("<div class='overlay'><p>Content</p></div>");
```